# Need to merge this queries

Tags: mysql

Need to merge this queries:-

```
select users.name as 'Agent', 
min(case when agent_activities.activity='login' then agent_activities.created_at end) as 'Login Time' , 
max(case when agent_activities.activity='logout' then agent_activities.created_at end) as 'Logout Time' 
from agent_activities inner join users 
on agent_activities.agent_id = users.id 
and date(agent_activities.created_at) = curdate() 
group by users.name 
order by users.name asc;

select created_name as 'Agent', count(*) as sale_count from dispositions where date(created_at) = curdate() and 
main_disp = 'Contactable' and sub_disp = 'Paid & Closed - Online' group by created_name order by sale_count desc;

select created_name as 'Agent', count(*) as dispositions_count from dispositions where date(created_at) = curdate() group by created_name 
order by dispositions_count desc;
```

There is common agent ID.

agent_activities have agent_id which is agent ID.
disposition have created_by which is agent ID.

Now Result is:-

```
Agent   Login Time          Logout Time
Agent   2018-09-27 11:43:44 2018-09-27 11:45:04
Hari    2018-09-27 11:10:41 2018-09-27 15:18:04
test    2018-09-27 10:26:54 2018-09-27 11:43:41
ttt     NULL                2018-09-27 11:21:06

Agent   sale_count
Hari VH 1

Agent   dispositions_count
ttt     2
Hari    2
Agent   1
```

Desired Result:-

```
Agent        Login Time             Logout Time          sale_count dispositions_count
Agent 1      2018-09-27 11:43:44    2018-09-27 11:45:04  1     2
Hari VH      2018-09-27 11:10:41    2018-09-27 15:18:04  1     2
test         2018-09-27 10:26:54    2018-09-27 11:43:41  1    33
ttt          NULL                   2018-09-27 11:21:06  1     0
```

Comment: You can use sub query to get this output

Comment: How please help?

Comment: Is there a way to join `dispositions` table to any of `agent_activities` or `users` table?

Comment: yes thru agent_id

Comment: try a left outer join on the 3 subqueries

Comment: any example? please tell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment based on joining condition for agent_id, I have tried to combine three queries into one.

Please check if this gives you desired output.

```
select u.name as 'Agent', 
min(CASE WHEN aa.activity='login' THEN aa.created_at ELSE null end) as 'Login Time' , 
max(CASE WHEN aa.activity='logout' THEN aa.created_at ELSE null end) as 'Logout Time' ,
SUM(CASE WHEN d.main_disp='Contactable' AND d.sub_disp = 'Paid & Closed - Online' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sale_count,
count(*) as dispositions_count
from agent_activities aa
inner join users u on aa.agent_id = u.id and date(aa.created_at) = curdate() 
inner join dispositions d on d.created_by = aa.agent_id and date(d.created_at) = curdate()
group by u.name 
order by u.name asc;
```

You can also use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on agent name to corelate all three queries.

```
select a.Agent as 'Agent', Login_Time, Logout_Time, sale_count, dispositions_count
FROM (
        select users.name as 'Agent', 
        min(case when agent_activities.activity='login' then agent_activities.created_at end) as Login_Time , 
        max(case when agent_activities.activity='logout' then agent_activities.created_at end) as Logout_Time
        from agent_activities inner join users 
        on agent_activities.agent_id = users.id 
        and date(agent_activities.created_at) = curdate() 
        group by users.name ) a
inner join (
    select created_name as 'Agent', count(*) as sale_count from dispositions where date(created_at) = curdate() and 
    main_disp = 'Contactable' and sub_disp = 'Paid & Closed - Online' group by created_name
) b on a.Agent = b.Agent
left outer join (
    select created_name as 'Agent', count(*) as dispositions_count from dispositions where date(created_at) = curdate() group by created_name 
) c on c.Agent = a.Agent
order by a.Agent asc;
```

Comment: the sales_count and disposition_count is coming wrong.. please verfiy

Comment: Are you sure that the join condition which you provided is correct? I tried to simplify your case with single query. You can also use a `left outer join` to consolidate results of your 3 queries.

Comment: please tell me how i cannot do.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check if that works for you.

Comment: The login and logout time is coming incorrect. it showing as TEXT LOGIN TIME